# Extending the Eclipse C Editor with all it's functionalities

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor

Say I have a custom editor inspired by the C Editor, but besides all its features I want to add several more of my own, and maybe change some functionalities from the C Editor to better suit me.

Now the core editor class can extend pretty easily the C Editor class and override methods or add more methods.

But how can I import extensions and extension points to make them work exactly as in the editor I'm extending?

Some buttons are greyed out, although the shortcuts work for some reason.(i.e "Show Whitespace Character" and "Toggle Block Selection"). Some buttons like the "Show Mark Occurence" are missing entirely. Some buttons like Next & Previous Annotation are greyed out and don't work by shortcut either.

I gather some of these are extensions added in the C Editor, but without trying to replicate them all from scratch, is there a way to inherit them in my editor?

The C Editor seems to be doing something like this, since it doesn't appear to contain the extension for the "Toggle Block Selection", which is present in the TextEditor it extends.

Comment: It feels like you are going about this the wrong way, i.e. you should be extending (in the plugin.xml as opposed to java sense) the existing C Editor. Perhaps you could explain what type of extensions you want to provide? Is it a new context menu, new syntax highlighting, something else? There are already lots and lots of places to extend the editor, and if you have a new extension point of the existing editor then the Eclipse CDT devs would be grateful for the needed hooks being contributed back.

Comment: Anyway, on to try to solve the question you are asking. Are you extending `org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CEditor`? e.g. you are probably getting key bindings because you are using the CEditor's key binding scope, see `initializeKeyBindingScopes`. Have you filled in the `contributorClass` field in the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point?

Comment: Yes!!! That was it! I added to the contributorClass field: org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CEditorActionContributor and now all buttons appear and work. Thanks! I probably am still missing a couple of it's features, which could be added some other way, but this really helped me a lot!

Comment: Great, I promoted that part of my comment to an answer, it would be great to have upvote/accept :-)

Comment: PS, Please ask new questions if you have them, if you tag them with eclipse-cdt I will probably see them.

Comment: Will do! There are probably a couple more buttons or features not yet added but, from what I tested, most stuff that was annoying me is gone. If I find anything I'll ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill in the `contributorClass` field in the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point.

From the [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_editors.html?cp=2_1_1_146):

> This class is used to add new actions to the workbench menu and tool
>   bar which reflect the features of the editor type.